# Can span contain redundant vectors in its set?

Tags: linear-algebra

I suppose it is probably answered somewhere, but I cannot for the life of me find the post. So here goes:

If $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^3$, then could $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ also span $\mathbb{R}^3$, where $v_4\ne v_1,v_2,v_3$?

Comment: In fact, if $S$ is a spanning set, and $S\subseteq T$, then $T$ is also a spanning set. This is the dual of the fact that if $C$ is linearly independent set, and $D\subseteq C$, then $D$ is also linearly independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In fact, we have the more general result:

> **Theorem.** Suppose that $S$ and $T$ are subsets of a vector space $V$ with $S\subseteq T$. Then $\operatorname{Span}(S)\subseteq\operatorname{Span}(T)$.

In our case, $S=\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ and $T=\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$ where each $v_i$ is a vector in $\Bbb R^3$. Then $\operatorname{Span}(S)=\Bbb R^3$ along with our above theorem gives
$$
\Bbb R^3=\operatorname{Span}(S)\subseteq\operatorname{Span}(T)\subseteq\Bbb R^3
$$
It follows that $\operatorname{Span}(T)=\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: thanks for the answer!